# DataLoader not randomly sampling in PyTorch

Tags: python, deep-learning, loader, pytorch

My DataLoader is returning me the same image with each epoch. My model is only looking at the same single image (indexed '0') each time (batch size is 1...although nothing changes with different batch sizes, anyways).

Here's my dataset, stripped down to the important bits:

```
class MyDataset(Dataset):

    def __init__(self, path, loader=pil_loader):
        self.path = path
        self.images = os.listdir(path)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        image = self.images[index]

    . . .
```

And here's the DataSet:

```
train_ds = MyDataset('/data')
```

And here's my sampler:

```
train_sampler = RandomSampler(train_ds)
```

And here's my DataLoader:

```
train_dl = DataLoader(train_ds, batch_size=1, sampler=train_sampler)
```

I'm not sure why it is returning me the same image each time, during 
 training.

Do I have `RandomSampler` incompletely set up? Or maybe I wrote the `__getitem__` incorrectly? I can't figure it out.

Comment: Cannot reproduce your error, I changed `__getitem__` to return the index (instead of the image) and I am getting different index at every iteration. I am using Pytorch 0.4

Comment: Instead of using `RandomSampler`, simply set `shuffle=True` in `DataLoader` constructor.

Answer (score 5):

Aha. Well, if anyone ends up here with the same issue, I figured out what it is and maybe this will help.

My definition of `__len__` was wrong.

I guess the random sampler depends on how you've set up the length method.

Mine was temporarily mocked up as

```
def __len__(self):
    return len(0)
```

instead of something real, like:

```
def __len__(self):
    return len(self.images)
```